# From the Graph API Explorer to valid URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, url-routing

How can I convert from **Facebook's Graph API Explorer** to a **valid URL**?  I'm trying to combine these elements:

- GET method
- `https://graph.facebook.com/1261653562?fields=id,name,albums.fields(photos.fields(picture,name),updated_time)`
- `Access_token=AAAC....`

I tried this:
`https://graph.facebook.com/1261653562?method=GET&fields=id,name,albums.fields(photos.fields(picture,name),updated_time)?access_token=AAAC.....`

but this returns me this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"a\".\" at character 63: id,name,albums.fields(photos.fields(picture,name),updated_time)access_token=AAACEdEose.........",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you got the answer???  plz share with me i have same issue...thx

Answer (score 2):

change  "?" before access_token to "&"

https://graph.facebook.com/1261653562?method=GET&fields=id,name,albums.fields(photos.fields(picture,name),updated_time)?access_token=AAAC

like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/1261653562?method=GET&fields=id,name,albums.fields(photos.fields(picture,name),updated_time)&access_token=AAAC